# How long does a 2 minutes animation takes? with 33 second for a frame, and 30 fps.?

Tags: rendering, animation

how long does a 2 minutes animation takes, my GPU is GTX 960m?

[image]

Comment: simple math: 2*60s*33=3960s=1h 6min, considering that not all frames are rendered in the same time add aprox. 10 min, so you have about 1h 15min. But that is not a question you should ask on Blender Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

**There is no standard time to render a scene.**

Long answer:

Rendering takes time.

If you render one frame, and multiply the render time by the number of desired frames, you can get the estimated render time for the whole project.

But even that might be an inaccurate number, as the time a scene takes to render has many variables that might change from frame to frame, mostly due the complexity of the scene (number of vertices and faces), the size and number of the textures, the complexity of the materials for the objects and the environment, the kind of simulations used, the number of particles, the final render size, number of samples, the kind of post processing needed, et cetera... On top of that render time also depends by the resources available on the host computer, which are unique to each user.